# It is necessary for the switch from Kernel mode to User mode to be a previleged instruction?

Tags: operating-system, kernel, cpu-architecture

When a CPU is executing kernel code, it is in privileged mode. Now when the CPU switches from kernel mode (privileged mode) to user mode, it is still in kernel mode. This made me feel that it is necessary for the CPU to be in Kernel mode during the switch. i.e. the instruction necessary for the switch is a privileged instruction.

Usually the CPU has a special mode bit, and a privileged instruction is needed to change this bit during the switch from kernel mode to user mode.

I have seen the xv6 implementation on the x86 architecture, where we have instructions like `IRET` which is a privileged instruction. But what I have read is specific to x86 architecture.

My question is, is there any example where the mode switching from Kernel mode to user mode is done by an instruction which is not privileged?

[Here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/11231/118790) in this answer, I see it is written that the switching instruction need not necessarily be privileged. But I do not get the intuition behind the same.

Is it such that the instruction for the switch though is usually executed in kernel mode, but it is actually an unprivileged instruction and as we know an unprivileged instruction can run even in kernel mode.

Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22130037/7571421) in this answer, I find that older editions of my textbook said that - switch from kernel to user mode is done by a privileged instruction, but this statement subsequently got changed in the newer editions. Do not know whether it is a typo which got corrected...

Comment: So the question is primary "Is there an **architecture** where a switch from the kernel to the user is performed using unprivileged instruction?", am I right? I don't know such architecture and I don't think it ever exists. Because "Usually the CPU has a special mode bit, and a privileged instruction is needed to change this bit during the switch from kernel mode to user mode." But of course, anyone could create such architecture.

Comment: There is no need for it to be a privileged instruction, because the effect is to move to unprivileged mode thus a kind of no-op if you are in this mode... That's all. Now for the sake of architecture complexity, it may be simpler to make it privileged.

Comment: x86 `iret` isn't privileged, though.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/iret:iretd defines what happens if you use it to pop a  RIP, CS, RFLAGS where that new CS selector is the same privilege level you were already in, even if that privilege level is 3 (ring 3 aka user mode).  It does have special effects if the new CS is less privileged than the original CS.

Comment: I verified that `iretq` is usable to jump from user-space to user-space on x86-64 (privilege level 3).  I had to push SS:RSP for `iretq` to pop, as well as RFLAGS and CS:new_RIP.  Took some digging, I hadn't realized it popped SS:RSP, too, even when returning to the same privilege level.  Working demo: https://godbolt.org/z/s8eEbGWd6 in NASM; assemble into a static executable with `nasm -felf64 iret.asm` && `ld iret.o -o iret` for Linux.  Same iret code should run under any OS, only the exit system call needs to be different.

Comment: https://tio.run/##ZVBNawIxFLzvr5iL0IJ70BYpeirFFqEH2e2hICJx92U3NCZr3qrrr7fZrLR@vEtehsxkZgQzbdb6GBvBm9MpJyl2uoYjHUlrxxH8bOweINH0MXwaBISPnAmtcTkTUKPqVeHsrnqgXD1GUaHtWmisuBaujrpjHPWUxAD3M4GhjJiFO0Jah1ky/br5nzkA1Y5LONFcXLiKemRyJQMGT@8Y8eBfnqnG@@frRwq2OBAyYTxGqEu/l8IUhENJHlOm0BRzTVXl179f5DasjRdvtels4N9edm3vJl2AM4ZiFNYQlEHzMopHz4GkSaAl9bHwxS@vc07aW2hcCp9s4eMuz6oH6364e@Coltu7UsODPnJL7AumHALJ9BuVI6lCAOV521uW0G1HLbXrJE3HSTpvvbemWpW13ROSrk9hcrylY0OHOJnNo2B@lw9Pp18 shows it actually runnable online; note the lack of segfault, or change `%if 1` to 0 and see it segfault when it pops an invalid SS:RSP.